# Accordion menu that is not closed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code in the controller of my menu, which allows me to display a sub-menu.

```
$scope.groups = [];
  $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
      $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
  };
  $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };
```

As you can see, I have a "Products" menu, and in this menu, I have 3 categories.
The code works, but unfortunately the categories are directly visible, while I would like to see that when you click on "Products"

```html
<ion-item class="item-stable item" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
  <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
  &nbsp;Products
</ion-item>
<ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" ui-sref="menu.disponibilites" menu-close="">Category 1</ion-item>
<ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" ui-sref="menu.organiseVisite" menu-close="">Category 2</ion-item>
<ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)" ui-sref="menu.trouverUnJeune" menu-close="">Category 3</ion-item>
```

In my css I have this

```
.list .item.item-accordion {
    line-height: 15px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    transition: 0.09s all linear;
  }
  .list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide {
    line-height: 0px;
  }
  .list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-add,
  .list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-remove {
    display: block !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller you my `$scope.groups` and in the page you put `group`. That's why you have this problem

Comment: True ! Oh my god, I did not notice it ^^'